# How to use tmap with <Plug>?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, plugin-system

I am wondering how shall I use `tmap` along with `<Plug>`.

Here is a snippet of the context where I am using it:

```
vim9script 

import autoload "../lib/foo.vim"

noremap <unique> <script> <Plug>DoSomething :call <SID>foo.DoSomething()

if !hasmapto('<Plug>DoSomething') || empty(mapcheck("<F2>", "t"))
    tmap <silent> <F2> <c-w><Plug>DoSomething<cr>
endif
```

When I use hit `<F2>`, nothing happens but a sound is emitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are a few issues with your example:

- the two first lines are irrelevant if you don't also include the content of the imported script, because a) we have no idea what `DoSomething()` does and b) the rest doesn't use the vim9script syntax anyway,
- the use of `<unique>` makes it impossible to iterate while testing,
- the conditional check is also irrelevant.

Here is an actual *minimal reproducible example*:

```
noremap <script> <Plug>DoSomething :echo 'Do something.'
tmap <silent> <F2> <c-w><Plug>DoSomething<cr>
```

The problem is that your `<Plug>` mapping is defined for normal mode, visual mode, and operator-pending mode (`:help :map`) while you are trying to consume it in a terminal mode mapping. Changing it to a terminal mode mapping is an easy fix:

```
tnoremap <script> <Plug>DoSomething :echo 'Do something.'
```

[image: Do something.]

Comment: `is defined for normal mode, visual mode, and operator-pending mode` auch!